# recv from epolled, nonblocking socket in edge-triggered mode

Tags: c, sockets, nonblocking, epoll

Can anyone give me an example for `recv` from `epoll`ed, nonblocking socket in edge-triggered mode? I ask because I have some troubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The man page, for EPOLLET set-up has:

The suggested way to use epoll as an Edge Triggered ( EPOLLET ) interface is below, and possible pitfalls to avoid follow.

```
i 
with non-blocking file descriptors 
ii 
by going to wait for an event only after read(2) or write(2)
return EAGAIN
```

Edit:
You can also call recv() or read() for x number of bytes until you receive less than x bytes.

If you don't do this you can create a starved situation where data remains in the socket buffer and prevents the ET activity on the socket.

What problem are you having?

Comment: i used it with nonblocking sockets and read while EAGAIN, example:

do {

        n = recv(sock, temp, sizeof(temp), 0);

} while (errno == EAGAIN);
but, sometimes program fall into indefinite loop there and errno == ENOTCONN

Comment: Do you mean: errno=0; do{ recv here} while(errno!=EAGAIN)

Comment: You should actually loop while `recv()` returns `> 0`.  If it returns `-1`, then look at `errno` - if it's `EAGAIN` then go back to polling it, otherwise handle the error (close the socket etc.)